# Look for partial name of cookie using Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

On my website I use a cookie to show or hide certain content. Depending on how users log in will determine what content is visible to them. i.e. If I log in with Facebook, my site looks for a cookie called "fbsr_3324". My problem is that the second part of the cookie name changes for every user (fbsr_2889 fbsr_9902 etc). I therefore want to know if someone can help and suggest how I can check for only the first part of the cookie name (i.e. only look for the existance of cookies starting with fbsr_

Here is the current current Javascript I use:

```
function checkCookie() {
    contentDiv=document.getElementById("cookieFb");
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("fbsr_")!=-1) {
        contentDiv.style.display="none";
    }
    else {
        contentDiv.style.display="block";
    }
}
```

Comment: It's possible to do it, but it's probable better to just have a cookie with the name `fbsr` and the value `2289`. Any key value store is most useful if you know the keys in advance.

Comment: I agree, but the problem is that it is the cookie is generated from from the "Login with Facebook" extension, so I can't change the names of the cookies that are generated

Comment: Maybe this could help: `document.cookie.split(/; */).map(function(c){return c.split('=')[0];})` That should give you array of the cookie names only, without values.

Comment: @Paulpro: What about `cookiename=foobar; expires=<some-date>; path=/;`? you'd map the expiry dates and paths as cookies, too. _and_ not all browsers support the `map` method yet

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem `map` is one of those functions you can expect everyone to have a SHIM for, but you have a good point about `expires` and `path`.

Comment: @Paulpro: _hope_ they have a shim for it, expect they don't, that's the safer attitude :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you're currently using would perform as if I were logged in using facebook, if I had a cookie set containing the value `'fbsr_haha, gotcha'`
Perhaps this is a job for regex:

```
/^|;\s*fbsr_[0-9]{4}\=[^;]+;/.test(document.cookie);
```

Should do the trick.
Expression explanation:

- `^|;`: Either start of the string, or a semi-colon
- `\s*`: followed by zero or more spacces
- `fbsr_[0-9]{4}`: matches fsbr_ and any sequence of 4 numbers
- `\=`: you could just write `=`, but sometimes you need to escape `=` (lookarounds), so best escape it once too often than not enough
- `[^;]+` anything but a semi-colon *at least once* or more
- `;`: a literal semi-colon

Where to use this expression:

```
function checkCookie()
{
    contentDiv=document.getElementById("cookieFb");
    if (/^|;\s*fbsr_[0-9]{4}\=[^;]+;/.test(document.cookie))
    {//facebooker!
        contentDiv.style.display="none";
        return;//return here, so you can leve the else out
    }
    contentDiv.style.display="block";
}
```

Well, that should do it.
However, I can't help myself, so if ever you get more familiar with JS, and feel like optimizing some of your scripts, consider this:

```
var checkCookie = (function(expr)
{
    var contentDiv = document.getElementById('cookieFb');
    return function()
    {
        contentDiv.style.display="block";
        if (expr.test(document.cookie))
        {
            contentDiv.style.display="none";
        }
    };
}(/^|;\s*fbsr_[0-9]{4}\=[^;]+;/));
```

This is an optimized version of the exact same code you have. ATM, your code will query the dom for an element with the ID `cookieFb` every time it is called, and it'll create an instance of RegExp, too. By using a closure, you can query the DOM once, and create the instance of RegExp once, and re-use it for each call.
It's a bit more efficient, and micro-optimization in this case, but I couldn't help myself ;)

Comment: Hi Elias. Thanks for your answer. Please excuse my utter stupidity, but I don't have much experience in Javascript. I know the expression you refer to, but where will this fit in with what I have? Again, sorry :(

Comment: @imieliei: updated, added 2 versions of the same function. For now, the first version is what you want, unless you understand what the second version does, and how to use it.

Comment: You truly are amazing. Thank you so much! I have another question though. In the /^|;\s*fbsr_[0-9]{4}\=[^;]+;/.test(document.cookie), where did you get the "test" from. Just wondering as I'm trying to see what is happening ad why. (It all works now, just wondering about the inner workings)

Comment: `test` is a method of the `RegExp` prototype. `/something/` is a regular expression literal, and is, therefore an object [check MDN on the method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FRegExp%2Ftest) and [on `RegExp` in general](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for more details

Comment: Ah I see!! First one makes sense now, but that second one I'm struggling to wrap my head around. One day I shall slay this Javascript dragon!

Answer (score 0):

I would do this. First break all cookies into an associative array

**Edit**

Function scraped from [here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/javascript-get-all-cookies/)

```
function get_cookies_array() {

    var cookies = { };

    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var split = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            var name_value = split[i].split("=");
            name_value[0] = name_value[0].replace(/^ /, '');
            cookies[decodeURIComponent(name_value[0])] = decodeURIComponent(name_value[1]);
        }
    }

    return cookies;
}
```

then in your checkCookie function loop through all cookie names and see if any starts with fbsr_

```
function checkCookie() {
    var contentDiv=document.getElementById("cookieFb");
    var cookies = get_cookies_array();

    contentDiv.style.display="none";
    for(var name in cookies) {
        if (name.indexOf("fbsr_")==0) {
            contentDiv.style.display="block";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: JS doesn't know of assoc arrays, it has Objects, and an `Array` is just an augmented version of that base `Object` constructor (`Object.getPrototypeOF(Object.getPrototypeOf([]))` in console shows that)

Comment: The solution works, independantly of how assoc arrays work internally in javascript...

Comment: Associative arrays just _don't exist_, it's either an Array instance or an object. Besides, your solution isn't full-proof. If I were to have a cookie `fbsr_a`, you'd consider that to be a FB cookie. You're also violating the few naming conventions JS has (`getCookieArray` instead of `get_cookie_array`, or better still `getCookieObject`)

Comment: Still, this is just nitpicking at code that basically works... (1) The function `get_cookie_array` was scraped from another site. (2) If I can't trust `fbsr_a` to be a FB cookie, then why should I trust `fbsr_1234` to be a FB cookie? It's just a name and any site can create a cookie with whatever name they want. There's the same likehood that site X created a cookie named `fbsr_a` or `fbsr_1234`.

Comment: (1) If the code was taken from another site, you should mention your sources. If not, you're violating any license that might be out there. Even so, if a cookie looks like `name=value=123;`, the code fails. However unlikely, expect the unexpected... (2) That's true, but `fbsr_a` doesn't even _look_ like a fb cookie, which follows the pattern `fbsr_\d{4}`, IMO, that's more than a _trust-issue_, I'd call that an omission that is easily rectified

Comment: I edited my response with the site where I got the function from. However, I'm not removing the answer as I consider the answer a valid alternative to the question asked--regardless of how many quirks other people may find with it.

Comment: I'm not _"pushing"_ you to remove the answer, not at all... I merely wanted make it clear that the term _assoc arrays_ is misleading, as JS doesn't really have arrays (the first version didn't even have the `Array` type!). That, and I also wanted, for completeness sake, point out a few glitches I noticed. I can be pedantic at times, I know, but I'm just trying to be correct and complete