# How to loop through cookie's lengths that starts with a specific word?

Tags: javascript

I have used this method on PHP in the past, but cant figure out how to do it in javascript.

Basically I want to loop through a list of cookie that starts with the word "order" each cookie order contains the word "order" plus a unique number to it. the unique number is unknown which is why i need a loop to find out a specific "order".

So the idea is i need to some how check if word "order" exist in a cookie once I find out how many then I can loop that many times.

This is what I have in PHP I would need something like this in javascript.

```
foreach ($_COOKIE as $name=>$value){
    if(strpos($name, 'order') !== false){
    //do something amazing!!!!
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Look for partial name of cookie using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972616/look-for-partial-name-of-cookie-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var x = document.cookie.split(';'); // your array of cookies

x.foreach(item => { 
//to make sure that your item contains "cookie"
if (item.indexOf('cookie')>-1){
//do your computation
}})
```

Comment: Thanks that seems the simplest version!

Comment: Yes, you're right! You just have to split your cookie and make a check to be sure it starts with cookie or not. `indexOf` will return -1 if `item` does not contain `cookie`

Comment: A problem i found, as I explained above, I need to check if "order(number)" exist, cookie with "order" will have a unique number on it at the end of the word, but i wont know the unique number, so i need a system where it checks the "order+number" without having to manually input a if statment such as if (item.indexOf('cookie11')>-1){, if you get what i mean

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var yourcookie;
    if (navigator.cookieEnabled) {
      cookieArray = document.cookie.split(";");
      cookieArray.forEach(myFunction);

      console.log(cookieArray)

      function myFunction(item, index) {
        if (item.split("=")[0] == " yourcookie" || item.split("=")[0] == "yourcookie") {
          yourcookie = item.split("=")[1];
          console.log("yourcookie " + yourcookie)
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Im having trouble understating your code.  line yourcokie = items.split... is yourcookie a variable that you didnt declare?

Comment: Thanks for the update. what does the parameter index has? as at the moment its empty

Comment: @Luke It is the array index of the cookieArray

Comment: thank you. there is just a little problem with your code i think. as the if statement will only be true if cookie name is "order" without any other values in it. where in my situation i have few cookies name "order" with a unique number at the end of it such as "order7". Is that right?

Comment: @Luke you can set cookie name order and set it value as you needed (7)

Comment: yeah I realised that, but I wont know what to set to as I dont know the unique number for the cookie "order(number)" one of the answer below provided this if (item.indexOf('cookie')>-1){ so i will use that instead i think.

Comment: @Luke you can remove if block if you need

Answer (score 1):

```
const theCookies = document.cookie.split(';');
theCookies.forEach(cookie => {
  // do something amazing !!
});
```